# Spring-boot automatically import applicationContext.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using `spring-boot` and would like to automatically import `src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml` file.

So far it only works if I explicit tell spring to import it:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
```

But spring-boot has so many default, maybe someone knows the "default" name for the app.xml file so that is gets picked up by spring-boot by default?

Comment: is it part of a web-application?

Comment: If it's a part of web application then you can use default name to load spring application context. If the name of `servlet-name` is `xyz` for `DispatcherServlet` in `web.xml` then it will load `xyz-servlet.xml` file automatically from class-path where you can import other spring configuration files using `<import resource="abc.xml" />`

Comment: It's a simple webapplication that should host a single SOAP webservice. So I have no explicit servlet name. The soap is wired by cxf.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no such feature for importing an XML configuration by default based on it's name or location.

Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-importing-xml-configuration) part of the documentation.

Comment: Correct. However, spring boot application can be used to import .properties (.yml) files automatically from classpath as a part of @EnableAutoConfiguration module.

Comment: @AbhishekShah That is true and is meant to include configuration properties. What OP is asking is whether or not a way Spring Boot would automatically import any specific XML files that define Spring beans

Comment: Agreed. Apologized for misunderstood. There no such kind of feature for auto import XML file for spring beans. You must have to specify it in your configuration class.

Comment: Link is dead 123

Comment: Thanks @DrunkenPoney, fixed now