# Inject property into applicationContext.xml as value (spring boot 2.2)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to inject a property into my applicationContext.xml file in my spring boot project:

Application file :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:navi.properties")    // <== injection here
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})   // <== load the xml setting file
public class CApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

As you can see, nothing fancy here... In my src/main/resources/navi.properties file :

```
USER_INFO_CLS=jp.co.xxx.yyy.fw.service.UserInfoService
```

in my `applicationContext.xml`, I am trying to inject this value :

```
<bean id="userInfoService" class="${USER_INFO_CLS}"/>
```

But `./mvnw spring-boot:run` returns the error below :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [${USER_INFO_CLS}] for bean with name 'userInfoService' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${USER_INFO_CLS}
```

I read many articles about it (like this [one](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)) and it sounds good....
Thanks

Comment: mmm, is there any particular reason behind mixing annotations and xml configurations?  Couldn't  it be a class annotated with @Bean?  Besides, the spring context doesn't know that `contextApplication.xml` depends on`navi.properties` and also it doesn't add xml files as configuration. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687754/spring-boot-automatically-import-applicationcontext-xml) and the linked documentation  section in that question and maybe [this[(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_applicationcontext_container.htm) and close your question.

Comment: The particular reason should be asked to the original developer :-) I took over this project: it contains sometimes annotations, sometimes XML definitions. I know it sucks but it's the reality and I neither have the time nor the budget to refactor it..  I forgot to write my annotation `@ImportResource({"applicationContext.xml"})` , sorry about that

Comment: Sry, but I don't have enough energy and time to go through docs and other sources on how the beans should be properly configured when dealing with such complicated situation. But [one thing I found here](https://www.java2novice.com/spring/read-property-file-xml-config/) is that the properties file should be included in XML file that usese it. I'm not sure if it'll work. And If mixing @ and XML works so fare, you really could try just to declare "userInfoService" bean in CApplication (from method) or from aother Configuration class in application context.